# absolute path for images in django

Tags: django, image, path

I'm new to web development and I'm recently asked to help building a website. I encountered an image issue that need ppl's help.

In the existing html code, they specify the image path as:

`<img src="/site-media/Logo.jpg" alt="Logo" style="margin:auto;display:block;height:70px;width:230px;"></img>` and it worked fine. However, when I try to use a software called wkhtmltopdf, which is a tool to convert html to pdf, I had problems. It seems that this tool only recognize absolute/relative path for images, but doesn't recognize patterns that django specifies in url.py like

> r'^site-media/(?P.*)$'

. As a result, my pdf files are generated without images. How do I get around with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried adding `<base href="http://yourdomain.com" />` to your html head? not sure if wkhtmltopdf would catch that, but it's worth a shot... you can also try adding the domain to your image tags, since `^site-media` is just a "folder" under your domain (according to the url rewriter)